# Employee of the month

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can 9 students become employee of the month for the next three months?

My solution is simply 9×9×9=729. Just asking if it's correct though.

Comment: You should explain why you’re multiplying 9 by itself twice.

Comment: If a student can be chosen multiple times, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If a student can be an employee multiple times, then it's correct.

Otherwise, the answer is simply $9\cdot8\cdot7=504$ since there are $8$ choices on the second month, $7$ on the third month.